# php regex match mysql data types

Tags: php, regex

php regex match mysql data types, using all of the mysql data types as subjects, ie

```
int(5)
varchar(10)
enum('yes', 'no')
```

I need arrays like so:

```
array( 'int', 5 )
array( 'varchar', 10 )
array( 'enum', 'yes', 'no' )    or    array ('enum', array('yes', 'no'))
```

so far I can match the contents of parentheses with:

```
/\(([^)]+)\)$/   and with    /\((.*)?\)/
```

all told I need:

```
number 1 - everything before the first opening parentheses

number 2 - everything inside the parentheses pair but not matching the parenthesis

number 3 - match the contents of the enum data type and return it's individual values (when values are delimited by "'" or by '"' or not delimited at all)
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I need a pizza and a good movie.

Comment: 1. how can I match everything before the first parenthesis and 2. match the values of the enum data type like so enum('yes','no') resolves to array('enum','yes','no' OR array('enum',array('yes','no'))

Comment: marc b go get a pizza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/([a-zA-Z\s]*)\((.*)\)$/
```

`([a-zA-Z\s]*)` - Matches zero or more alphabets or spaces

( - Matches opening parentheses
(.*) - Matches any string
)$ - Matches closing parentheses at end of the line

PHP:

```
preg_match ('/([a-zA-Z\s]*)\((.*)\)$/', $your_string, $matches);
$matches[1] -> Type int, enum, etc.
$matches[2] -> Size 10, (yes, no), ..
```

Comment: preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\s]*)\((.*)\)$/', 'enum("yes", "no")', $matches);
    var_dump(explode("\", \"", substr($matches[2], 1, -1)));                 thanks again

Comment: it works like a charm!